# Не скачивается библиотека в python в ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

Пытаюсь скачивать библиотеки для python в ubuntu server 16.04, но мне вылазит ошибка (на последней строке):

***AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'***

Это ошибка начала вылазить после того, как я установил библиотеку "requests" (её через pip3 uninstall удалить не получается). Что делать?

UPD. При вводе в консоль просто pip3 выводится такая-же ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930195/attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-pathlike-after-command-virutalenv

Comment: Сначала в гугл ищите...

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки с полным трэйсбэком. Также укажите какая версия Python исопользуется.

Comment: Александр, это я пробовал, не работало.

Comment: Insolor, я прикрепил скриншот

Comment: Установите версию `certifi==2021.10.08` (это зависимость requests, в которой у вас вылетает ошибка), в ней еще не добавлено PathLike.

Comment: Надеюсь, requests не через sudo устанавливали?

Comment: Insolor, блин, я через sudo. Сейчас виртуалку переустановлю

Comment: @Александр, в гугл отправлять [нельзя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Insolor, а сначала нужно certifi установить?

Comment: Insolor, я установил certifi, а потом requests, но всё равно ошибка